# how to show a dialog in mvvm android

Tags: android, mvvm, android-livedata

showing a dialog, start activity in MVVM is a view responsibility.
in view, you have an instance of VM but in VM you don't have the instance of the view.
so the solution is using live data and observes in view, right?
but how about time I don't want to use live data? how can I show a dialog when I don't have access to view?

Comment: I don't know when or where you want to show your dialog but you can send the view to the VM from your xml like this: 

android:onClick="@{(v) -> viewModel.onClick(v)}" 

hope it will help you.

Comment: yes but my problem is in the definition of VM you cannot show a dialog or start activity this is view duty my question is how can I show dialog in view when I'm in VM decide to show a dialog and don't have access to view

Comment: maybe try to use interface in the VM.

Comment: like MVP? so what's different between MVP and MVVM?

Comment: So we are forced to have a referrence to the custom dialog in order to execute .show() in the activity?

Comment: no, we need to use either livedata or Rxjava in our ViewModel I strongly encourage you to watch this talk about MVC, MVP, MVVM https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QrbhPcbZv0I&t=1155s

Comment: technically if we become more precise in how Observer patterns works, yes we need to have a reference of our views in our ViewModel but its managed with observer library that we use like RxJava or Livedata. so we can completely unit test ViewModel classes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using some version of the observer pattern is the only way! Even defining an interface and making view implement that interface is basically using observer pattern. What java Observable, Rx Observable and LiveData do is, they make this process super easy.